# SQL multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that has the options to take in Ids from three different columns I am concatenating all the `where` clauses together and then I `EXEC` the command.

Just wanted to see if there is a better way to do this?

```
IF ((ISNULL(@GuidelineIds, '')) <> '') 
BEGIN
    SET @whereClause = @whereClause + ' AND glinks.GuidelineId IN (SELECT val AS linkType FROM dbo.Split(''' + @GuidelineIds + ''','',''))'
END

IF ((ISNULL(@SubCategories, '')) <> '') 
BEGIN
    SET @whereClause = @whereClause + ' AND lt.LinkTypeID IN (SELECT val As subCategories FROM dbo.Split(''' + @SubCategories + ''', '',''))'
END

IF ((ISNULL(@LanguageIds, '')) <> '') 
BEGIN
    SET @whereClause = @whereClause + ' AND glinks.LanguageId IN (SELECT val As languages FROM dbo.Split(''' + @LanguageIds + ''', '',''))'
END
```

Comment: `a better way` - better in which sense? Without dynamic SQL? Faster? More readable?

Comment: Sorry more readable and faster

Comment: Is this Sql Server? Where are the values coming from (what is calling this procedure)?

Comment: Yes it is SQL Server there is an ashx page calling the procedure. The values coming in can be for LanguageIds 1,2,3,4 or just LanguageIds 1

Comment: It could be cleaner if you used [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). You would only need 1 type (so it seems) for a table that contains a integer? column. Then you pass this in 3x and then you can use proper joins instead of filtering (although filtering is OK as well but I would recommend the use of EXISTS over IN).

Comment: And if you try with a dummy condition initially where you add your other conditions? for example: `WHERE 1 = 1 (AND ...) + (AND ....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by this way

```
Select *
From ...
WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND ((ISNULL(@GuidelineIds, '')) = '' OR glinks.GuidelineId IN (SELECT val AS linkType FROM dbo.Split(''' + @GuidelineIds + ''','','')))
    AND ((ISNULL(@SubCategories, '')) = '' OR lt.LinkTypeID IN (SELECT val As subCategories FROM dbo.Split(''' + @SubCategories + ''', '','')))
    AND ((ISNULL(@LanguageIds, '')) = '' OR glinks.LanguageId IN (SELECT val As languages FROM dbo.Split(''' + @LanguageIds + ''', '','')))
```